# Vectorized year/month/day operations with NumPy datetime64

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create vectors of NumPy datetime64 objects from 1-D vectors of years, months, and days, and also go the reverse direction, that is extracting vectors of years, months, or days from a daily datetime64 vector. I'm using NumPy 1.7.0b2.

For example, suppose

```
years = [1990, 1992, 1995, 1994]
months = [1, 6, 3, 7]
days = [3, 20, 14, 27]
```

Now I want to create a np.datetime64 vector of length 4 using these years, months, and days. Is there a way without using a Python loop?

Going the other direction, suppose `dates` is a vector of datatype np.datetime64 and the frequency is daily. Then I would to be able to something like `x.DAYS()` and get back a vector `[3, 20, 14, 27]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
def compose_date(years, months=1, days=1, weeks=None, hours=None, minutes=None,
              seconds=None, milliseconds=None, microseconds=None, nanoseconds=None):
    years = np.asarray(years) - 1970
    months = np.asarray(months) - 1
    days = np.asarray(days) - 1
    types = ('<M8[Y]', '<m8[M]', '<m8[D]', '<m8[W]', '<m8[h]',
             '<m8[m]', '<m8[s]', '<m8[ms]', '<m8[us]', '<m8[ns]')
    vals = (years, months, days, weeks, hours, minutes, seconds,
            milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds)
    return sum(np.asarray(v, dtype=t) for t, v in zip(types, vals)
               if v is not None)

years = [1990, 1992, 1995, 1994]
months = [1, 6, 3, 7]
days = [3, 20, 14, 27]

print(compose_date(years, months, days))
```

yields

```
array(['1990-01-03', '1992-06-20', '1995-03-14', '1994-07-27'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do it without some sort of looping, but I inlined it a bit with a list comprehension:

```
years = [1990, 1992, 1995, 1994]
months = [1, 6, 3, 7]
days = [3, 20, 14, 27]
np.array(['{0[0]}-{0[1]}-{0[2]}'.format(x) for x in zip(years, months, days)], dtype='datetime64')
```

Going back the other way, you have to convert each item to a regular `datetime`.  You can do this by calling `astype(object)`, which works for the whole array or for individual objects.  Which one you do probably depends on how your using the data.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#assembling-datetime-from-multiple-dataframe-columns) without explicit looping (the code is taken from the pandas documentation):

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
   ....:                    'month': [2, 3],
   ....:                    'day': [4, 5],
   ....:                    'hour': [2, 3]})
   ....: 

In [32]: pd.to_datetime(df)
Out[32]: 
0   2015-02-04 02:00:00
1   2016-03-05 03:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

of course you can 'floor' the date times to 'day' and return a numpy array with `.values`